# Google cloud datalab deployment unsuccessful - sort of

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-datalab

This is a different scenario from other question on this topic. My deployment almost succeeded and I can see the following lines at the end of my log

> [datalab].../#015Updating module [datalab]...done.
>   Jul 25 16:22:36 datalab-deploy-main-20160725-16-19-55 startupscript: Deployed module [datalab] to [https://main-dot-datalab-dot-.appspot.com]
>   Jul 25 16:22:36 datalab-deploy-main-20160725-16-19-55 startupscript: Step deploy datalab module succeeded.
>   Jul 25 16:22:36 datalab-deploy-main-20160725-16-19-55 startupscript: Deleting VM instance...

The landing page keeps showing a wait bar indicating the deployment is still in progress. I have tried deploying several times in last couple of days.

About additions described on the landing page -

- An App Engine "datalab" module is added. - when I click on the pop-out url "https://datalab-dot-.appspot.com/" it throws an error page with "404 page not found"
- A "datalab" Compute Engine network is added. - Under "Compute Engine > Operations"  I can see a create instance for datalab deployment with my id and a delete instance operation with `*******-ompute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` id. not sure what it  means.
- Datalab branch is added to the git repo- Yes and with all the components.

I think the deployment is partially successful. When I visit the landing page again, the only option I see is to deploy the datalab again and not to start it. Can someone spot the problem ? Appreciate the help.

I read the other posts on this topic and tried to verify my deployment using - "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/source/overview?project=" I get the following message-

> The API doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it

Answer (score 1):

You can try looking at the App Engine dashboard [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/services), to verify that there is a "datalab" service deployed.

If that is missing, then you need to redeploy again (or switch to [the new locally-run version](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/)).

If that is present, then you should also be able to see a "datalab" network [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/networks/list), and a VM instance named something like "gae-datalab-main-..." [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances). If either of those are missing, then try going back to the App Engine console, deleting the "datalab" service, and redeploying.